# Removing spaces and returning multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

So Im trying to do a fuzzy search on users and return their names and emails. For some mad reason whoever made this database decided to make the email column a nchar(320). So I need to remove the spaces from the email. I was able to do it. But the way I did it only returns single variables. Im not sure how to get it to return entire columns with the spaces removed from the email addresses. Heres what I have now.

```
USE [TADB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ResourceSearch]    Script Date: 05/01/2015 14:29:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResourceSearch]
@Name varchar(25) = null    

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Email varchar(100)
    DECLARE @ResName varchar(100)

    IF @Name = '' OR @Name IS NULL
        Set @Name = NULL
    Else
        Set @Name = @Name + '%' 

    SELECT @Email = EMAIL_ADDRESS 
    FROM [RESOURCE]
    WHERE 
        (@Name IS NULL OR (RESOURCE_NAME LIKE @Name))

    SELECT @ResName = RESOURCE_NAME
    FROM [RESOURCE]
    WHERE 
        (@Name IS NULL OR (RESOURCE_NAME LIKE @Name))

    SELECT @ResName, REPLACE(@Email, ' ', '')

END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the last 3 SELECT statements with this to display all columns with the whitespaces removed from the email:

```
SELECT RESOURCE_NAME, REPLACE(EMAIL_ADDRESS, ' ', '')
FROM [RESOURCE]
WHERE 
    (@Name IS NULL OR (RESOURCE_NAME LIKE @Name))
```

You are only getting single variables because you are setting the first value from the result into a variable, while just selecting on that column will return the entire result.

Also, when the select statements have the same FROM/WHERE clauses with conditions you can combine the 2 statements into 1 and set the variables separately. But in this case it looks like you don't need the @Email and @ResName variables.

Comment: Cheers man, that worked. I had tried to combine them but I was doing it when using the variable and it didnt work so just separated them out. Thanks again.